# how to create search engine friendly urls in a php mysql blog system?

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I have a website in which there is a standard blog template page and the content is fetched via post method from a "MYSQL Database". My "URLs" look like `mysite.com/blog.php?id=2`. What i want is too make them look like `www.mysite.com/the-title-of-the-blog`.

I have tried Google, but it has not helped me. what most articles miss is that they do not mention how to tell the server to identify the changed "URL".
Please help me do so.

What i expect:

1. probably a php function to convert it
2. a .htaccess code to tell this to my server

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll be wanting to use the mod_rewrite web server extension.  You'll find that frameworks like WordPress and Joomla! contain good examples of this.